# What is the past pathway to become a .net developer?

Tags: asp.net, web

I want to create a learning plan for myself and for other novice students, lets say that I want to be able to create professional websites using asp.net.
C#, HTML, CSS , JS ASP
What do you recommend ?

Comment: You can use some video tutorial web sites like Pluralsight. PS: You have free access to it for 6 months from your Visual Studio Online account. You will find all kinds of tutorials there! HTML, CSS, ASP.NET... whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

For me, I started learning by browsing tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AYoipyqOkQ). But still, the best way is through experience (at work). Learning the hard way as they say. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you should learn C# very well,

   you can refer to this link to learn C# --- [Click here to learn C#](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/)
2. Then you should have clear concepts on HTML/HTML5.

   Refer to this link [Click here to learn HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)
3. Then you should learn CSS , as you know CSS helps us in designing the   website, and it looks pretty much attractive.
   Refer to this link [Click to learn CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)
4. Then you should learn JS, to make the page more dynamic. 
   Refer to this link [Click to learn Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

**Javascript helps us to program the behaviour of webpage**

5. Then you should learn a database language such as **mysql** to store data into the database.

*If you are using **Visual Studio** for learning ASP.NET using C#, you can  follow the procedures given below : -*

a. First learn how to use the forms - using textboxes, buttons, image etc.
 b. Second, learn how to configure the database using `.sqlexpress`?  **ADO.NET**
 c. Third, learn to use grid view, data-table

or you can make a simple website of where you can insert,  update,search,delete of the employees in a certain organization.

d. Then learn AJAX.

If you are not using `Visual Studio` , you can follow the link given below
  [Learn ASP.NET](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/index.htm)